# Extract rows from multiple sheets into one and exclude any row with #N/A

Tags: excel, vba

I have one sheet of data where I need to extract the values from multiple columns and assign them a value. Column A is a string where column B is the assigned value.  Columns C and D are vlookups based on column A and they will need the assigned value from column B as well.  Please see the screenshots.  I would need to compile a list on a separate sheet.  Ideally column A would have the data from columns A, C and D from the other sheet and column B would have the assigned values.  Only caveat is I need to exclude any row that has #N/A

Any macro that may work would be very helpful!

[image]

[image]

Code I was using

```
Sub Life_Saver_Button()
Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long

Set S1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set S2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastrow
S1.Cells(i, 1).Copy
erow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S1").Paste Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S2").Cells(erow, 1)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S1").Cells(i, 2).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S1").Paste Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S2").Cells(erow, 2)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S1").Cells(i, 3).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S1").Paste Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S2").Cells(erow, 1)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S1").Cells(i, 4).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S1").Paste Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S2").Cells(erow, 2)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S1").Cells(i, 5).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S1").Paste Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S2").Cells(erow, 1)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S1").Cells(i, 5).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S1").Paste Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S2").Cells(erow, 2)

Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S2").Columns().AutoFit
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test1()

    Dim LastrowA As Long, Lastrow As Long, cell As Range, Code As Long
    Dim Desc As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastrowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For Each cell In .Range("A1:D" & LastrowA)

            If Not IsError(cell.Value) = True And Not IsNumeric(cell.Value) = True Then

                Desc = cell.Value
                Code = .Range("B" & cell.Row).Value

                Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                If LastrowA = Lastrow Then
                    .Range("A" & Lastrow + 2).Value = Desc
                    .Range("B" & Lastrow + 2).Value = Code
                Else
                    .Range("A" & Lastrow + 1).Value = Desc
                    .Range("B" & Lastrow + 1).Value = Code
                End If

            End If

        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: I keep getting The error appears as “run-time error 13 – Type mismatch”. error for line  Code = .Range("B" & cell.Row).Value

Comment: Could you please tell me the value of .Range("B" & cell.Row).Value?